# How to use a restful request to populate an XBL control?

Tags: xforms, xbl

I hope some of you XForms gurus can help. I have a large XFroms model that is populated via a bunch of xbl controls. One of the controls needs to use the XML that is retrieved from a restful url which returns me the XML for the model.

I assume a XForms submission (GET) will do the trick, but I cannot get my head around how to achieve this.

Could one of you XForms gurus please post a small example of how this can be achieved.

Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: To clarify. I want to add a readonly section to my XForm, this data will come from another system via a webservcie which will provide me with the XML.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would typically use an `<xforms:submission>` to retrieve that XML data into an instance, and point your XBL control to that instance. If you are not familiar with the XForms submission mechanism, you can learn more about it, and about other XForms constructs, in the [XForms tutorial](http://wiki.orbeon.com/forms/doc/developer-guide/orbeon-forms-xforms-tutorial).